# Jhipster: Context-path change showing errors in Administration section

Tags: java, spring-boot, jhipster

I have changed the context path in my jHipster application at 
resources/config/application.yml
`server.servlet.contextPath: /myContext`

After these changes, jHipster generated UI unable to make API calls from the Administration section.
jhipsterVersion": "6.8.0"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching and debugging it for couple of days, finally found the solution so if you are working on the Jhipster 6.8 since I have changed the default context to custom one, you need to change the same thing in your webpack.common.js `new BaseHrefWebpackPlugin({ baseHref: '/myContext/' }),`.
And it will do the magic for you.

Cheers !!!